# Randomly select 4 items of a randomly selected category

Tags: mysql, subquery, random

I need an idea how to construct this query.

I have a web page. each time the page is refreshed, I want to select data from a random category, and to select no more than 4 random items from that category.

For example, with different types of music as my categories, and songs from that type of music as my items, three separate refreshes might return:

First refresh:

```
categoryid     name        title
    212         rap      making it
    212         rap      falling hard
    212         rap      kill it
    212         rap      gone wide
```

Second refresh:

```
categoryid     name        title
    200        blues     under you
    200        blues     loving
    200        blues     moving
    200        blues     mine world
```

Third refresh:

```
categoryid     name        title
    312        rock      lazy 
    312        rock      nice 
    312        rock      stoned
    312        rock      my world
```

I believe I'm supposed to use a sub-query to return this.

So, the category should be selected at random, the songs within that category should be selected at random (unless there are 4 or fewer songs, in which case they'll all be shown), and the order of the songs should be random.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is quite incomprehendable. Please include some sample data, table structure, and expected output showing rows and columns.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, you want to return a category at random, and, I'll guess you want to return up to 4 items from the category. What you've included is (I assume) your desired output. We need to know more about the limits on the query. Ultimately, this sounds like a web page, and it's quite possible that some of the restrictions (maybe even including the random category) would be determined there, which would be out-of-scope for this site.

Comment: @RDFozz yes thats what i want to accomplish 4 at least just 4 random values with same catid displaying on random

Comment: To clarify further: the 4 selections from the random category should also be randomly selected? Also: "at least 4" would mean there would be cases where more than 4 would be apprpropriate; "just 4" would mean only 4, no matter haw many more than 4 there are. What I suspect you want is "at most 4". If there are only 1, 2, 3, or 4 rows for the category, then return those rows; if there are more than 4 rows, then return 4 randomly selected rows from what's available.

Comment: it wont b more than 4 if there are catid that only got 2 of d same it will return 2 but not more than 4 result  cause it will b display on rand not asc or desc

Comment: @RDFozz yes that way well said

Comment: @david - I've edited the question for you, based on your comments. It should make things clearer. If I've gotten anything wrong, you can [edit] the question yourself to correct it; if I've gotten everything wrong, you can click the link that tells you when the last edit was made, and roll back to a previous version.

Comment: hi all any idea

Comment: any idea people

Comment: "Bumping" has no impact in this forum (other than to annoy the Answerers).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item FROM Items ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

Will select 4 distinct items at random from that table.  You should be able to build both of your requirements based on this pattern.

Each time the query is run, a different 4 will be picked.  But...  One set of 4 may overlap another set of 4.  If this caveat is not to your liking, the code becomes more complex -- you have to remember what you have already displayed, that that involves passing information from one page to the next.  That is tricky since HTML is "stateless".